# find the argument of this expression without expending it

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the argument of $z=(3-4i)^{15}$. I know that if i can keep expending this i will eventually find the argument. My real question is, Is there a quicker way of doing this problem without expending it

Answer (score 1):

Write the complex number inside the bracets in polar form: $a = r \,e^{i\theta}$ for some $r>0$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ and thus 
$$a^{15} = \left(r \,e^{i\theta}\right)^{15} = r^{15}\,\left(e^{i\,\theta}\right)^{15} = r^{15}\,e^{i\,15\,\theta}$$
Meaning for us the argument is $15\,\theta$ and the primary argument is the smallest equivalent angle between $0$ and $2\pi$. Thus it just remains to find the argument of $(3-4i)$.

Answer (score 0):

For any complex $z$,
$$\arg{(z^n)} = n\arg{z} \pmod{2\pi}, $$
so find the argument of $3-4i$ and multiply it by $15$.